# Could not find driver, connecting php to sql server

Tags: php

Good day,

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft sql server database with the use of php 
I downloaded the php driver for sql server and placed them in the extension folder.

I made some adjustment to the php.ini file as well, to include the new extensions.

as the webserver, I am using a server that is similar to XAMPP but instead, this server is a portable one where by you can place it on a usb stick and use other machines to do your developmental work. It is called USB WebServer.

Every time I run the php script, i keep getting the error that says:  "could not find driver." I know that this error is an indication that my connection to the database is not successful. I don't know what I have done wrong and I m in need of some help.

The following is my code to connect to the database:

```
  $DB_HOST = 'DESKTOP-AKQUS0J\SQLEXPRESS';
  $DB_USER = '';
  $DB_PASS = '';
  $DB_NAME = 'slddweb';

  try{
 $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$DB_HOST};Database={$DB_NAME}"," 
 {$DB_USER}","{$DB_PASS}");


   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

the above script is stored in a file by the name of connect.php

And I used the following code to detect which version of php I am currently using:

```
 echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

which stated that i am using php version 5.4

I downloaded the drivers for php to work with sql server from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
I downloaded the third file upon clicking the third check box.

Two files by the names of:
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll AND  php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
were copied to the extension folder which is located into php folder.

these file names were placed into the extension section of the php.ini file.

After i did the above, I restarted the server  ...when i run the php script, i get the error message from the connect.php

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `php -m` to check whether the extension is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure sql server extenison is loaded in PHP. u can use `php -m` to check it.
the extension named `php_sqlsrv`.
And

- SQLSRV40 for PHP 7.0+ (Windows、Linux)
- SQLSRV32 for PHP 5.6、5.5、5.4(Windows)
- SQLSRV31 for PHP 5.5(Windows)
- SQLSRV30 for PHP 5.4(Windows)